# Can <uses-library> be used to check if an app is installed and how? As opposed to a shared library?

Tags: android, installation, package, manifest

I have an app widget project, which relies that a corresponding app is installed.

So, the paackage name of the required app is

```
com.radlmaier.saintscalendar
```

In the app widgets manifest, I have the following tag inside the  tag:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.radlmaier.saintscalendar" android:required="true" />
```

Now, when the app is not installed, the widget installation fails, as it should.
But if the app is installed, the widget installation fails, too, with logcat saying:

```
05-19 22:28:35.359: E/PackageManager(14680): Package com.radlmaier.saintscalendarwidget requires unavailable shared library com.radlmaier.saintscalendar; failing!
```

I am clearly missing something here. 
Is it not possible to use the  tag to check for an installed package as opposed to a shared library?
Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it not possible to use the tag to check for an installed package as opposed to a shared library?

That is most certainly not possible. `<uses-library>` is for requiring SDK add-ons (e.g., Google Maps).

> I have an app widget project, which relies that a corresponding app is installed.

Android does not an application dependency mechanism, so if you want this, you will have to roll it yourself. Personally, I would recommend simply combining these into one application.

Comment: I would do that but the app carries quite a huge assets folder, and therefore preferred install location is the external sd card. As both need to be compatible with minimum of SDK 7 / Android 2.1, I need to have the widget installed on the phone. So, separating both was the only way to go... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).setClassName("com.radlmaier.saintscalendar", "com.radlmaier.saintscalendar.yourclassname");
boolean isInstalled = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0).size() > 0;
```

If it's not installed, and you want to send them to Play Store to install it, try this:

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
marketIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.radlmaier.saintscalendar"));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```